# How to find nuget package of a project that references a missing package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a project ABC that does not reference the package AssemblyNameXyz directly but when running the application ABC, I see the error
`Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyNameXyz, Version=4.0.0.142 ...' - The system cannot find the file specified.`

How do I know which installed package in my project might be referencing this package that was not found during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

In Bash terminal, in nuget package folder (`~/.nuget/packages`), run command `find . -name "*.nuspec" -exec grep "VERSION_NUMBER" {} +`

The “VERSION_NUMBER” is the one that the exception/error indicates e.g. as per question, its `4.0.0.142`

```
$ find . -name "*.nuspec" -exec grep "4.0.0.142" {} +
./AssemblyNamePqr/2021.1.0.27/AssemblyNamePqr.nuspec:        <dependency id="AssemblyNameXyz" version="4.0.0.142" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
```

The result shows that `AssemblyNamePqr` refers the deviant/missing dependency.

Notes

1. Make sure to clear nuget cache if reproducing the issue on a environment different from where the issue occurs.

**More details**

[NU1605](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605) was ignored probably which prevents things breaking from scenarios like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#direct-dependency-wins

A “direct” nuget package installed to a project might have a (“indirect package”) dependency that is missing. Because .Net loads assemblies lazily (Reference: https://michaelscodingspot.com/assemblies-load-in-dotnet/ - official MS link?) the problem is caught at runtime with errors like above.